# Omniauth can't find route

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, omniauth

I'm trying to implement Omniauth with my Rails 3 app. I followed the tutorial from the [Railscast episod 205](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1?view=comments), but can't get it to work. When I call the '/auth/twitter' (it doesn't work with any provider) Rails complains it can't find the appropriate route (it tries to load my default route).

I added omniauth.rb under `config/initializers/`, put `gem 'omniauth'` in my Gemfile, and ran bundle install.

I'm not sure how to debug this problem nor what information to provide to help understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found a solution. I added the following to my routes.rb file:

> get   'auth/:provider' => 'authentications#passthru'

and to my authentications controller:

```
  def passthru
    render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", :status => 404, :layout => false
  end
```

Not sure why I had to do that, but it's working...

Comment: Hey...This worked for me too. Did you get any more details about why this works?

Answer (score 1):

Here were my steps to get it working:

1) Add omniauth to your Gemfile

2) Add omniauth strategy to your Gemfile (`omniauth-linkedin` for example)

3) Run `bundle install`

4) Add the omniauth initializer in `config/initializers/omniauth.rb`

5) Add the match `auth/:provider/callback` => `users#omniauth` route to `routes.rb` (point it to the controller/action where you'll handle the authentication response)

6) Build the action to handle the authentication response in the controller you referenced in step #4

7) Restart your web server

**The default `/auth/:provider` route wasn't recognized for me until I restarted Apache.**

Answer (score 0):

You have to add 'omniauth-twitter' to your gemfile, and

```
:strategy_class => OmniAuth::Strategies::Twitter
```

to your `omniauth.rb`, at the end of the twitter provider.

Then it will recognize the /auth/twitter path.